# Spring Expression Language to search anywhere in the object graph

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-el

In Spring Expression Language is it possible to perform an exhaustive search on an object graph and return the first node matching?

For example,

```
BookingEvent event = getEvent();
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("metadata.bookerInfo.traveler.userBusinessInfo.employeeId");
Assertions.assertEquals("EM1", exp.getValue(event));
```

The above one works but in SpEL can I write an expression to find the `employeedId` anywhere under `metadata` or anywhere in the `event` object?

If yes, is it possible to return all `employeeId`s instead only the first one?

I am using `spring-boot` 3.0.11